# Adding or reordering multiple elements in a template without editing the template file

Tags: pimcore

In my pimcore exam I'm doubtful about this question: "What concepts can be used to add or reorder multiple elements in a template without editing the template file?"

- Blocks
- Areabricks
- Renderlets
- Scheduled Blocks

Which answers are correct and why?

My opinion is: Blocks, Renderlets and Scheduled Blocks because they are editables and I think only Areabricks must be defined in template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks and areabricks are correct.

Renderlets in Pimcore are used to render specific data or content within a template. They are typically used to display dynamic content that is fetched from a specific source, such as a database or API. However, Renderlets themselves do not provide a mechanism for adding or reordering multiple elements in a template without editing the template file. They are more focused on rendering specific data rather than managing the overall structure or layout of the template.

Scheduled Blocks, on the other hand, are used to display content at specific times or dates. They allow you to schedule the visibility of certain content blocks within a template. While Scheduled Blocks provide a way to control when content is displayed, they do not offer a direct solution for adding or reordering multiple elements in a template without editing the template file.

However, Blocks and Areabricks are specifically designed to address the need for adding or reordering multiple elements in a template without modifying the template file directly. Blocks allow you to create reusable content elements that can be easily managed and inserted into templates, while Areabricks provide predefined areas within templates where you can add and arrange content elements. These concepts provide a more flexible and dynamic approach to managing the content structure within templates without the need for template file modifications.